# Tomcat say: No payload parameter on [OnMessage] method

Tags: websocket

[the error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxyEd.jpg)

My annotation at ServerEndPoint:
`@ServerEndpoint(value = "/portal/{action}/{num}/{msg}", configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class)`

My annotation at onMessage method:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(@PathParam("action") String action, @PathParam("num") String num, @PathParam("msg") String msg, Session session)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know. It is necessary to add a parameter to receive the other message. So just remove the third annotation of the parameter of the [Method] annotated by @OnMethod.